# Trouble with inverse in group of order 3. Why can't I chose any inverse for all elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let a group $G = \{e, a, b\}$, with operation $\cdot$. Ie, $(G, \cdot)$, where $e$ is the identity, that is $c\cdot e = e\cdot c = c, \forall c\in G$. I was told there is only one possible cayley table for this. But why?

Consider:
$a = a^{-1}$ and $b = b^{-1}$, that is $a\cdot a = b\cdot b = e$. As you can see, there exists inverse of $a$, which is $a$. There exists inverse of $b$, which is $b$. And evidently, there exists inverse of $e$, that is $e$. As you can see, for all elements in $G$, there exists an associated inverse. Thus, inverse axiom is satisfied. Thus a group by definition!

Then why can't I chose these inverses and build a different Caylay table? The lectures I've been reading says that if $a\cdot a = e$ then $b\cdot b = e$. Why is that? Shouldn't I be free to chose any inverse I want? (as long as is inside $G$ ofc, and as long associativity is respected, ofc). Perhaps I mis-interpreted the axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be free to chose any inverse I want?

You are free, provided that it does not contradict anything. It actually can lead to contradictions in nontrivial ways, that's why we need all those theorems to understand groups.

Suppose that $G=\{e,a,b\}$, $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1} = b$. Let's see what $ab$ will be. We have three options:

- $ab=e$. Multiply this by $a^{-1}$ on the left to get $a^{-1}ab=a^{-1} \Rightarrow b = a^{-1} = a$, a contradiction to $a \neq b$.
- $ab=a$. Multiply this by $a^{-1}$ on the left to get $a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}a \Rightarrow b = e$, a contradiction to $b \neq e$.
- $ab=b$. Multiply this by $b^{-1}$ on the right to get $abb^{-1}=bb^{-1} \Rightarrow a = e$, a contradiction to $a \neq e$.

So, if there are only three *distinct* elements in the group, it cannot happen that $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1}=b$.

Answer (score 2):

> Then why can't I chose these inverses and build a different Cayley table?

You can certainly try, but you will run into contradictions with other axioms, i.e. anything you try from that point on will not satisfy associativity or possibly some other properties.

If we go back to your second paragraph: you can't say that you already have a group because you're not done defining the operation on it — what are the values of $a\cdot b$ and $b\cdot a$? And you jump to conclusions too quickly: satisfying only one axiom (of having inverses) is not sufficient — you must satisfy **all** axioms. So far you have this as your Cayley table:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  & e & a & b \\
\hline
e & e & a & b \\
a & a & e &   \\
b & b &   & e
\end{array}$$

Group axioms imply that each row and each column of the Cayley table has to contain all elements exactly once without repetition. So the blank in the second row has to be $b$ as the only missing value in that row. But at the same time looking at the third column, the same blank has to be $a$ as the only missing value in that column. This is a contradiction. That's one way to demonstrate that choosing $a\cdot a=e$ and $b\cdot b=e$, even though it may look fine at first, actually can't work.

Comment: Why is that "each row and each column of Caley table has to contain all elements exactly once without repetition"? Well... Regardless of the values of $a\cdot b$ and $b\cdot a$ it will respect associativity (I think). I have tried out. Also, it already respects inverse (as I said in the question). And identity. Seems like a group to me.

Comment: Assume you have the same value twice in a row corresponding to some $a$. That means that $a\cdot b=a\cdot c$ for some $b\neq c$. But we can multiply this equality by $a^{-1}$ from the left getting $a^{-1}\cdot(a\cdot b)=a^{-1}\cdot(a\cdot c)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot b=(a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot c$ $\Rightarrow$ $e\cdot b=e\cdot c$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=c$, contradicting our choice of $b$ and $c$. Similarly for columns. That's uniqueness. And each element has to be present in any row because in the row of $a$ we can find any $x$ as the entry for $a\cdot (a^{-1}\cdot x)$.

Comment: Hm.. Nice. Thanks. =).